# Normed vector space and uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $V, V'$ be normed vector spaces and $f: V\to V'$ a linear
>   transformation.
>
> a. Prove that if $f$ is continuous at one point it is continuous
>   everywhere and in fact uniformly continuous.
>
> b. $f$ is continuous if and only if the set
>   $\{\frac{||f(x)||}{||x||}:x\in V, \ x\ne 0\}$ is bounded.

For $a$ I assumed $f$ is continuous at a point $v_0$. Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $v\in V$ we have $||v - v_0||<\delta$ implies $||f(v) - f(v_0)||<\epsilon$. So then I must show that for other points $x,y$ it is also continuous, how can I do that? And I am stuck on $b$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Use the linearity of $f$ for ($a$). For if $\|x - y\| < \delta$, then

$$\|f(x) - f(y)\| = \|f(x - y)\| = \|f(v_0 + (x - y)) - f(v_0)\|$$

But now $\|\Big(v_0 + (x - y)\Big) - v_0\| = \|x - y\| < \delta$.

---

For ($b$), first assume that $f$ is bounded with constant $M$. Use the boundedness to estimate

$$\|f(x + h) - f(x)\| = \|f(h)\|$$

On the other hand, if $f$ is continuous, try to use part (a).

Comment: From linearity then $||x -y|| = ||(x-y+v_0) - (v_0)||<\delta$ implies $||f(x-y+v_0) - f(v_0)|| = ||f(x) - f(y) -f(v_0)-f(v_0)||<\epsilon$ so $f$ is continuous?

Comment: @Tom Yes, pretty much. So we've shown that $\|f(x) - f(y)\|$ is small, and that's the definition of continuity.

Comment: Thanks! For $b$ can you explain it more please?

Comment: How can you estimate $\|f(h)\|$ in terms of $\|h\|$ using boundedness? If $f$ is *uniformly* continuous, try writing $\|f(x) - f(y)\|$ in terms of $\|x - y\|$, with a constant.

Comment: So I have to bound it by some $M$ which I get that $M\|x - y\|
<\delta$ but then would $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{M}$? And how can I show it conversely?